# calayer setneedsdisplay instant call drawlayer:incontext

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, calayer

i have a layer called basicLayer, and i have some paths need drawing in function drawlayer:incontext,
so i called [basicLayer setneedsdisplay]; which will call drawlayer:incontext atomaticlly, but it didn't called drawlayer:incontext instantlly, so my question is how can i instantlly call drawlayer:incontext after [basicLayer setneedsdisplay]; this consumed me serval hours, please help me?

```
[basicLayer setNeedsLayout];
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
```

i need draw some paths and then sleep 1 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this! Calling `sleepForTimeInterval:` is generally not a good idea. Especially on the main thread (where I assume you are) it's an absolute no-go because you are blocking the entire UI that way.

If you need to wait for a second, do something like `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` (or an equivalent call with Grand Central Dispatch). The call to `setNeedsLayout` is fine.

Comment: You need to be more specific then. As Ole has mentioned, the sleepForTimeInterval: is likely your issue. If removing that does not solve the issue, then check for other places where you block the thread. Remember, the drawLayer is not called before the main thread has a chance to return to the runloop.